# Spark [ScalaTest]: Overall TDD steps for customised Spark-based transformers

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

We all use customised transformers and estimators in our Spark pipelines. Creating a transformer or estimator is pretty strait forward in terms of value/param/method usage. For example in case of transformers:

1. Use a set of parameters
2. Use their set/get methods
3. Use transformer, transformerSchema, and copy methods.

My question here is what are the overall TDD steps for writing transformers? The acceptance test is clear, get this DataFrame and return this DataFrame with this schema; however this does not provide full test coverage.